# Opening a Modal Pop Up window

Tags: android, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal pop up window with a TextView and two buttons when the user "clicks" on a ListView item.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the `AlertDialog.Builder` class.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

The above link should provide you with all the necessary information.